# mysql select column value from another column

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, crud

I have a mysql query

`select host, domain from table`

```
Output:
host                        domain
host1.abc.com               abc.com 
host2.abc.com               null
```

I want to change the query so that I get `domain` value from the first column by stripping out the `host` part. I don't want to query the `domain` value from the table because some of it is blank

This way domain for `host - host2.abc.com` would be
`abc.com`

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP TABLE bleach;

CREATE TABLE bleach (`host` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO bleach (`host`) VALUES ('host1.abc.com');
INSERT INTO bleach (`host`) VALUES ('host29.abcdefg.com');

SELECT * FROM bleach;

SELECT `host`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`host`,'.',-2) FROM bleach;
```

OUTPUT:

```
host                 SUBSTRING_INDEX(`host`,'.',-2)
host1.abc.com        abc.com
host29.abcdefg.com   abcdefg.com
```